# Minimal color classes [Asking for sources]

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

Given any simple finite graph $G$, we may define an ordering on the set $C = \{c : V(G) \rightarrow \mathbb N$ | $c$ is a proper coloring of G $\}$ in the following way: given two colorings $c_1$ and $c_2$, $c_1 < c_2$ if:

- $c_1$ uses fewer colors than $c_2$
- If they use the same number of colors but $c_1$ has a smaller 'smallest color class' than that of $c_2$
- If none of the above apply, but the second smallest color class of $c_1$ is smaller than that of $c_2$
- ...

I particular, if neither $c_1 < c_2$, nor $c_2 < c_1$, then all of their color classes are of the same size.

The above sounds fairly trivial, so I am sure some research effort has been put into it. I was unable to find any sources though. So I kindly ask for any kind of article, book, or summary in this topic.

P.S. I apologize for my poor grammar.

Edit: To clarify my motivation: I would like to examine the properties of a 'minimal' coloring respect to the above ordering. Each 'minimal coloring' is also an optimal coloring (coloring that uses the least possible number of colors), so it is natural to say that the notion of 'minimal coloring' in the above sense is a generalization of optimal coloring.

Comment: By "well coloring" I suppose you mean that adjacent vertices have different colors? These are usually called "proper colorings" in English, I've never seen "well coloring" before.

Comment: It might make it easier to find the reference you are looking for if you could tell us something about the motivation, which is not at all obvious.

Comment: this sounds a lot like partition refinement? As in, the function c is the 'same' as a partition of the vertices, and c1 < c2 is similar to p1 finer than p2 - where p1 and p2 are the equivalent partitions. Maybe I'm wrong ...

Comment: @gilleain Partition refinement is a partial order that captures at least a little bit of the information here (if we reverse it). But we also want to say that $c_1 < c_2$ if, for example, $c_1$'s color classes are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ and $c_2$'s color classes are $\{1\}, \{2,3\}, \{4\}$, even though neither is a refinement of the other.

Comment: @bof I edited my question to 'proper coloring'. My motivation is simply curiosity. Similar to the chromatic number, we could introduce the notion of 'minimal coloring' respect to the above ordering. I am interested in the properties of such minimal coloring. I would like to see if it works with classical theorems/conjectures about the chromatic number (and eventually see if it helps to solve certain open problems...).

Comment: @gillean A minimal coloring respect to the above ordering captures 'global' properties of the graph similarly to the chromatic number. Even though it 'should' capture more information about the graph, I have not been able to use this additional information yet.